# JavaScript converts to PC timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

Javascript is possible to convert a date in a specified time zone, for example Europe/Berlin and pass it to the time zone of the browser?

Comment: What do you mean with "and pass it to the time zone of the browser"?

Comment: Not using built–in methods. The only string specified to be correctly parsed by the Date constructor is some of the ISO 8601 formats and only for UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries that do this. While not a particularly difficult problem from an engineering standpoint, there are a surprising number of edge cases that are difficult to get right.

Suggested Library: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Steps to do this manually:

1. Calculate the target date's UTZ timezone offset
2. Calculate the browser's UTZ timezone offset
3. Find the total timezone offset between the target and the browser.
4. Adjust for Daylight savings time issues (yup this is the hard part)

Comment: The local timezone can be ignored since a Date's time value is UTC. Just add or subtract (as appropriate) the target offset and use UTC methods to read the resulting values.

Comment: Thanks a lot you all, I'll going to test these answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on:

```
// parse in a particular time zone
var m = moment.tz("2014-12-31T01:23:45", "Europe/Berlin"); 

// switch to the browser's local time zone
m.local(); 

// format some output
m.format(); // example: "2014-12-30T16:23:45-08:00"
```

You can do this in one line if you like.

```
moment.tz("2014-12-31T01:23:45", "Europe/Berlin").local().format()
```